# Need to Send HTTP-error-500 when an Exception occurs

Tags: rest, exception, struts2, http-status-code-500, struts2-rest-plugin

I have designed a RESTful backend using `struts2-rest-plugin`.
My front-end is `Ember.js` **CRUD** app.

> When I try to create a new record with duplicate ID my server is
>   showing an exception.

How do I send it as HTTP-error-code-500 to my ember.js app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26845204/573032

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of Struts I just needed to return DefaultHttpHeaders.

```
 public HttpHeaders create() {
        try{
            employeesService.save(model);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            return new DefaultHttpHeaders("DuplicateId").withStatus(409);
        }
        return new DefaultHttpHeaders("success")
            .setLocationId(model.getId());
    }
```